# react switch v4 doesn't work and throw all route's

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement, frontend, reactcsstransitiongroup, react-router-dom

i don't know how solve my problem. This is react route code
How i know, switch must throw one route component in my Base, but he throw all route's in Router.I don't know how work with this object( in image) and have to get key for ReactCSSTransitionGroup

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nzkf91delcvuo2f/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9.png?dl=0

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Route,
Switch,
browserHistory
} from 'react-router-dom'
import render from 'react-dom'
import Base from '../../layouts/BaseLayout'
import Contacts from '../contacts'
import Product from '../product'
import Main from '../main'
class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Base>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Main} key={'1'} location={location}/>
                    <Route component={Product} path='/product' key={'2'} location={location}/>
                    <Route component={Contacts} path='/contacts' key={'3'} location={location}/>
                </Switch>
            </Base>
        </Router>
    )
}
}
```

and this is my Base class

```
class Base extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
}
render() {
return (
    <div>
        < Head />

        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example"
                                 transitionEnterTimeout={1500}
                                 transitionLeaveTimeout={1500}
        >

            {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
                key: this.props.location
            })}
        </ ReactCSSTransitionGroup >
        < Footer/>
    </ div >
    );
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but look at your Base component which is cloning all the children.

Comment: but switch shold throw one route, which in this

Comment: Doesn't matter what switch is doing if you are then creating all of the components elsewhere.

Comment: ok, i add remove this and add {this.props.children}, but it not solve my problem with ReactCSSTransitionGroup animation

Comment: The official docs have an example of how to use transitions. If you study that example, you should be able to figure this out. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/animated-transitions